# Rails HAML assets precompile with initialize_on_precompile false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, haml, assets

I'm going a little nuts here.

I have 2 servers (heroku, same configuration) in 2 environments (staging, production).

Staging compiles my /assets/templates on demand and caches it without a problem.
Production serves the file uncompiled as html (being haml markup)

The problem is: the configuration of the 2 environments is identical (except mail server)

Gems, environment config and yml are the same.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

The haml assets where "precompiled" on both servers but raw. Staging didn't get the file missing and re-compiled because assets where compiled for production.

Now I'am stuck with adding haml to the asset compile pipeline with initialize_on_precompile false.

**staging.rb / production.rb**

```
config.cache_classes = true

config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.serve_static_assets = true

config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"

config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true

config.assets.digest = true

config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.js modernizr+respond.js polyfills.js )
config.assets.precompile += %w( gp.js ad.js richmarker.js infobox.js )

config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compress=true

config.threadsafe! unless $rails_rake_task

config.i18n.fallbacks = true

config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger.const_get(ENV['LOG_LEVEL'] ? ENV['LOG_LEVEL'].upcase : 'INFO')

config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
  :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
  :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
  :allow_reload => false
}

Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = true
```

Comment: That was a tricky one. The pre-compiler never finished compiling the haml assets. And the staging served them compiled at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to add the haml into the load. Add the following to application.rb

```
Sprockets.register_engine '.haml', Tilt::HamlTemplate
```